# Laravel skip sending mail based on conditions

Tags: laravel, email, model-view-controller, laravel-5.7

I'm looping through users in my controller function and sending an email to each user, but there's a special user who will sometimes be in the list who shouldn't receive emails.

I'd like to put an `if` statement in to skip that loop iteration if it's that user, but when I add `return`, `return null` etc, or just nothing in my `if/else` in the mailable class build function I get

```
InvalidArgumentException
Invalid view.
```

I could add the conditional in the controller and I'm sure that would be fine, except I have these emails in a whole load of my controllers so would be writing the conditional many times. If I can get it into a central location (and the mailable class is the only one I'm aware of) then I can write it once.

EDIT: the loop code has been requested so added below, but this is just one of many email loops in my controllers so NOT where I'd like to add my conditional.

```
        $objNotification = new \stdClass();
        $objNotification->message_body = "stuff";
        $user_ids = DB::select('select user_id from users_to_things where thing_id = ?', [$thing->id]);
        foreach($user_ids as $user_id) {
            $user = User::find($user_id->user_id);
            $objNotification->receiver = $user->name;
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NotificationEmail($objNotification));
        }
```

Here's my mailable class's build function (where I DO want to add the conditional if at all possible):

```
public function build()
{
    if($this->notification->receiver == 'the special user') {
        return;
    } else {
        return $this->from('somebody@somewhere.com', 'Sender Name')
                    ->subject('some subject')
                    ->view('emails.notification')
                    ->text('emails.notification_plain');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the loop you are using. We can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: No problem @Jerodev, I've added that and the mailable build function also (where I'd like to edit).

Answer (score 0):

What you want would conflict with the Single Responsibility Principle. The class is only suppose to send the email.

The `build()` in your mailable class returns error cause it expect you to return a message ( subject ,body, template or `view`, etc) for your mail.

1.) maybe instead you can assert a fake mail in your condition;

2.) Create a function in email class

```
public function needSend($mail)
{
    ... loads of conditions
    return (condition) ? true : false;
}
```

then

```
if ($mail->needSend($mail)) {
    \Mail::send($mail);
}
```

3.) Or the easiest but dirtiest way is you can put the condition inside your `Controller` in your `for` loop

```
foreach($user_ids as $user_id) {
   $user = User::find($user_id->user_id);
   $objNotification->receiver = $user->name;
   if(condition == true) continue;
   Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NotificationEmail($objNotification));
}
```

You can also read this thread on github. https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/519

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think you've read the question properly - I'm trying to avoid adding it in the controller loop because I have many of these loops so would be writing the same conditional many times. I'm asking if it's possible to write once in a central location (such as the mailable class).

Comment: Thanks Julius. I'm a Laravel novice so only have a vague understanding of what goes where, but wouldn't all of these solutions require edits to the controllers so every single user email loop would have to be edited?

Comment: Thanks, I did see that post (looked like a perfect match) but was disappointed that the responses were ideological criticisms rather than practical (whereas the desire to not re-write the same code many times has clear value!).

Answer (score 0):

Using the notification class, check your condition like a suppression list or maybe runtime condition. Return an empty array and it'll exit.

```
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return $notifiable->notificationSuppression()->exists() ? [] : ['mail'];
}
```